# Не ставится gem jazz-hands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems

Я новичек в программировании и в RoR. Возникла проблема с установкой гема Jazz-hands. С другими гемами проблем не возникало. Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Вот результат в терминале:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jazz_hands:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debugger-1.6.8/ext/ruby_debug
/home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160728-10202-1gsdnhy.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./230/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in `open'
    from /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1392:in `copy_file'
    from /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:486:in `copy_file'
    from /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:403:in `block in cp'
    from /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1571:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    from /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1585:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    from /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:1569:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    from /home/denis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:402:in `cp'
    from extconf.rb:83:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:82:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:82:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/denis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out
denis@denis-R528:~/Dropbox/Programming/my_first_project$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Гем `jazz_hands` обновлялся в последний раз в 2013](https://github.com/nixme/jazz_hands). И у него **неверно указаны зависимости**. Недостаточно строго.

Он прикручивает к Rails-консоли `debugger`, который работает **только с Ruby 1.9**. Начиная с Ruby 2.0 (в т. ч. в 2.3) вместо него используется `byebug`, а `debugger` больше не работает.

Т. е. фактически этот гем требует Ruby не новее 1.9. В текущем состоянии. Хоть в [гемспеке](https://github.com/nixme/jazz_hands/blob/master/jazz_hands.gemspec) это и не указано.

Выход один: **отказаться** от этого гема, и следуя его Readme, собрать его аналог по кусочкам. Большая их часть просто устанавливается и работает, возможно с подключением в `.pryrc`.

---

*Вероятно, можно форкнуть его и заменить отладчик на новый, а изменения предложить в гем или выпустить самостоятельно. Тогда ответом станет "обновите его". Можете отработать процесс отправки pull request!*

Comment: Спасибо, я так и думал что скорее-всего несовместимость с версиями либо rails  либо  ruby)